# Google's example function with requestAnimationFrame - explanation?

Tags: javascript, document-ready, requestanimationframe

I came across a weird function proposed by google. It looks like some kind of document ready function. I can't get my head around it.

Can anyone explain it?

```
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;

if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(someInitFunction, 0); });

else window.addEventListener('load', someInitFunction);
```

This function in proposed on Google's developer site: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

first it will assign requestAnimationFrame function to a variable;

```
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
```

then it will check if it exists ( implemented by the browser ) or not

```
if (raf){
 // requestAnimationFrame is available to use
 // we can use it directly or by the reference 
 // raf(someCallback) or requestAnimationFrame(someCallback) both equal
}else{
 /* requestAnimationFrame is not implemented thus can't be used */
}
```

in `true` case it will use `requestAnimationFrame` to push `someInitFunction` to the very end of callback queue on RAF execution ( to be executed after all the main tasks and callbacks )

in `false` case; which means requestAnimationFrame is not implemented natively it will fallback to use the old school method to run `someInitFunction` on window's "load" event

---

Take your time to investigate execution order of this snippet;

> Run it multiple times, ideally in different browsers. "sync raf" sometimes printed after all main queue's task (after "a"); Most of the times printed after all main queue's tasks and callbacks ( right before "async raf");
>
> Notice that "async raf" is always the latest thing to run in any situation, any browser;

```js
function a () { console.log("a") }
function b () { console.log("b") }
function c () { console.log("c") }
//same as others, but with the settimeout hard-coded
var d = function () { 
  setTimeout(()=>console.log("d"),0)
}


a();
setTimeout(b,0);
requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>console.log("async raf"),0);
    console.log("sync raf")
});
setTimeout(c,0);
d();
```